# Sorting CoreData objects Using enum

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, enums

I need to sort a core data object which contains Persian alphabet. I am using NSSSortDescriptor. Unfortunately Apple do not support persian alphabets and the sorting is not working correct and based on persian alphabet. I am going to define persian alphabet as an enumeration in my application after then, sorting the data object based on it. Please help how can sort the data object based on predefined order.

NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES];

Comment: I am using SQLite-based Core Data store. apple did not support the persian alphabet, and when I'm using NSSortDescriptor at fetch request (for sort my personal in table view) but NSSortDescriptor using Arabic alphabet for sorting and my sorting is not working correct. I want to find an approach for define persian alphabet in array and using this array for sorting core data object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a SQLite-based Core Data store, this isn't possible. With that kind of persistent store, fetch requests are converted to SQL and executed in SQLite. But SQLite doesn't know anything about enumerations declared in your app, so it can't use them. Only persistent properties on your managed objects are available. If you were using a binary persistent store (`NSBinaryStoreType`) you might be in luck-- but that has other problems, like the fact that Core Data loads the entire persistent store into memory at once.

Having said that though, it would be **very** surprising if Apple did not support the Persian alphabet. Pretty much everything related to text uses Unicode nowadays, and as a result nearly every writing system known to humanity is supported (even ancient systems that are no longer used). For details, check out the [Unicode 8.0 Character Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)-- everything there should be supported. If you're having trouble using the Persian alphabet with Core Data, I suggest asking a new question with details of what you're doing (including some example text for those of us who aren't familiar with your alphabet) and what's going wrong.

Comment: One has to add, that sorting in-memory (not at fetch request) should work with `NSSortDescriptor`. Of course, this includes firing a fault of the fetched objects. But in many cases this will happen independently of the sorting.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I want to use this approach, I should using NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]  initWithKey:@"lasname"ascending:YE Sselector:@selector()] ? how can do this an what is it selector in this case should be?

Comment: It does not depend on the sort descriptor itself, but on what you want to apply the sort: In a fetch request you cannot apply a sort descriptor of that form, because your Objective-C code cannot be executed in SQL as Tom explained. If you have an unsorted array in memory (i. e. *after* a fetch), you can use your approach on that *array*. However, I completely agree with the second paragraph of Tom's answer: It takes very much energy from me to believe that the persian alphabet is not supported correctly.